# Merge or extend drives in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, disk-space, memory-management

In the below screenshot, system drive (`C:`) is almost full. There is also free disk.

[image: Free disk]

The merge or extend option is not available for system drive.

[image: option unavailable]

For free space, all options are disabled.

[image: option unavailable]

> How to merge or extend the system drive with the free space?

Comment: Why don't you try using 3rd part softwares like easeus partition master etc.?Follow http://www.partition-tool.com/resource/manage-partition/resize-c-drive.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extend your c: partition you need to have unallocated space next to the c: drive but you have free space so to change that to unallocated you can do two things:

First:You can assign a name to the free space and delete it but as it is clear from your screen shot that you can't assign a name to the free space so that leads to second option.

Second:Windows Disk Management utility has limited functionality so I advise you to use 3rd party applications like partition wizard,easeus partition master etc. I think these applications will list your free space as unallocated else try assigning a letter or deleting the free space from these tools and then you can extend your c: partiton.

For your convenience :http://partitionwizard.com/video-help/extend_partition/extend_partition.html

http://www.partition-tool.com/resource/manage-partition/resize-c-drive.htm

Answer (score 0):

Right click the free space partition (97.65GB/partition with green bar above) and delete volume if delete option not available use shrink volume, there will be a partition that return to unallocated, then right click C drive and click extend volume then adjust the volume following the unallocated one.

Comment: Hi @Jusup - I have updated my question. The option is not available